# Check microphone privacy setting on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, winapi

I've a WPF application written in c# that use microphone device with naudio libraries, which on Windows 10 update build 1803 has added privacy setting to access at microphone.

If user has allow privacy flag, my application work fine otherwise my application not working. So how can I to check this privacy setting by c#?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a direct way to figure out whether your application has these permissions, so your best option is to try to access the microphone and catch the error when it occurs.

```
try
{
// code to access microphone
}
catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException e)
{
// notify user application can't work without microphone permission                
}
```

Comment: You can do it if you have registry access probably because likelihood is the configuration data for it is stored there, but I wouldn't know if OP does or not in his circumstances. I guess there are .NET APIs for working the registry and always P/Invoke to Win32 API. Generally speaking though, most configuration data for things like this is stored in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this is one way to solve it. Unfortunately it might catch other errors not related to the Microphone Privacy Settings.

```
/// <summary>
/// With Windows 10 update 1803 came an option to deny access to the microphones on an OS level.
/// The option covers all soundcards installed into the PC (Magnum/Callisto is a soundcard)
/// </summary>
public static class MicrophonePrivacyProbe
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Test if Microphone Privacy Settings are to restrictive for microphone access.
  /// </summary>
  /// <returns>True if microphone is accessible</returns>
  public static bool Allowed()
  {
    bool access = false;
    var devices = new CaptureDevicesCollection();

    if ( devices?.Count <= 0 ) return false;

    var captureDevice = new Capture(devices[0].DriverGuid);
    CaptureBuffer applicationBuffer = null;

    var inputFormat = new WaveFormat();
    inputFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond = 8000;
    inputFormat.BitsPerSample = 8;
    inputFormat.BlockAlign = 1;
    inputFormat.Channels = 1;
    inputFormat.FormatTag = WaveFormatTag.Pcm;
    inputFormat.SamplesPerSecond = 8000;

    CaptureBufferDescription bufferdesc = new CaptureBufferDescription();
    bufferdesc.BufferBytes = 200;
    bufferdesc.Format = inputFormat; 

    try
    {
      applicationBuffer = new CaptureBuffer(bufferdesc, captureDevice);
      access = true;
    }
    catch (SoundException e)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
      applicationBuffer?.Dispose();
      captureDevice?.Dispose();
    }

    return access;
  }
}
```